# GitLab cache key: files - file does not exist

Tags: node.js, gitlab

I have a short pipeline. And it constantly fails with not being able to find the cache:

```
node:
    stage: Install
    cache:
        - key:
              files:
                  - package.json
                  - package-lock.json
              prefix: node
          paths: [node_modules]
        - key: npm
          paths: [.npm]
    rules:
        - changes:
              - package.json
              - package-lock.json
    script:
        - npm i


mocha:
    stage: Test
    script:
        - npm test
    cache:
        - key:
              files:
                  - package.json
                  - package-lock.json
              prefix: node
          paths: [ node_modules ]
          policy: pull
```

This pipeline run well on `Branch 1`

And on `Branch 2`, the `node` job skipped, as expected, however, job `mocha` failed with

```
Checking cache for node-313ff968911abee510931abad7ccd29ed21954b5-17-non_protected...
WARNING: file does not exist                       
Failed to extract cache
```

This is strange because it should use cache from the run of `Branch 1` pipeline.

I use shared runners with Merge Pipeline if it's important.

Comment: What are the (hashed) cache keys of the caches created/requested by the two pipelines? Do they agree? (You can see them in the job logs, e.g. `Creating cache cae438740f0893066b2f126dbc106e3ac6733b74-non_protected...` and `Checking cache for cae438740f0893066b2f126dbc106e3ac6733b74-non_protected...`)

Answer (score 4):

even though this is an old question asked but it might save someone else day for using cache in different branches, what I understand your cache is working as expected in `feature` which is probably `non-proctected` branch and when you're trying to create a merge-request to merge your changes to a `protected` branch probably `dev/main`.

Basically `protected` and `non-protected` branches don't share cache in Gitlab CI by default as mentioned in their docs.

> By default, protected and non-protected branches do not share the cache. However, you can change this behavior.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/

**Use the same cache for all branches**
*Introduced in GitLab 15.0.*

If you do not want to use cache key names, you can have all branches (protected and unprotected) use the same cache.

The cache separation with cache `key` names is a security feature and should only be disabled in an environment where all users with Developer role are highly trusted.

To use the same cache for all branches:

- On the top bar, select Main menu > Projects and find your project.
- On the left sidebar, select Settings > CI/CD.
- Expand General pipelines.
- Clear the Use separate caches for protected branches checkbox.
- Select Save changes.